# How are pvalues calculated in the corelation and how do I get pvalues for biserial.cor?

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance

In `Hmisc` package in R or with `cor.test`, we can get the pvalues for pearson or any other correlation. I wanted to calculate biserial and polyserial correlation for data with numeric and ordinal values.

I am using functions `biserial.cor` from `ltm` package and `polyserial` from `polycor` package. I am wondering how can I calculate, pvalues to test if the correlations are statistically significant in case of biserial and polyserial correlations.

Example from the help function:

```
library(ltm)
biserial.cor(rowSums(LSAT), LSAT[[1]])
```

Comment: You can use the standard error from polyserial.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? Thanks! How do I calculate std.err (preferably pvalues) from values returned polyserial function when std.error is set to TRUE?

Comment: ?polyserial tells you what it returns and you can then extract the standard error. You get a p-value by dividing the estimate by its standard error. Note you are assuming the estimate is normally distributed which for absolute values close to unity is almost certainly false.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but I get ... variance (which is a matrix), chisquare, degrees of freedom, in addition to type, rho and cuts, what would be the formula for standard error.  Thanks!